# R extract unique row values in a column in a dataframe in a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe, duplicates, lapply

I have a list of dataframes called `list` and it looks like this:

list[[1]]

```
X1 X2 X3 X4
a  1  b  c 
d  2  e  f
g  3  h  i
j  4  k  l
```

list[[2]]

```
X1 X2 X3 X4
a  1  b  c
d  2  e  f
g  2  h  i
j  3  k  l
```

list[[3]]

```
X1 X2 X3 X4    
a  1  b  c
d  2  e  f
g  3  h  i
j  4  k  l
```

I have been trying to use lapply to loop through the list and print out all the duplicates in column X2 of each dataframe.

I'm not able to figure this out. Would appreciate any help. Thanks.

I've tied

```
lapply(list, function(i) {
  if(length(unique(i[X2])) != length(i[X2])) {
    print(i[X2][duplicated(i[X2]))
  } else {
    print("No duplicates")
  }
})
```

Comment: Try `lapply(list, function(x) names(which(table(x$X2) > 1)))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `lapply`, find out the `duplicated` indices in `X2` column and print the `unique` duplicated values.

```
lapply(list_df, function(x) {
   inds <- duplicated(x$X2)
   if(any(inds)) unique(x$X2[inds]) else "No duplicates"
})

#[[1]]
#[1] "No duplicates"

#[[2]]
#[1] 2

#[[3]]
#[1] "No duplicates"
```

Using `list_df` instead of `list` since `list` is an internal R function.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `table` to find out the frequency of values in the column 'X2', extract the `names` of the output where the frequency is greater than 1

```
lapply(list, function(x) {
   x1 <- names(which(table(x$X2) > 1))
     if(length(x1)== 0) "No duplicates" else x1})
#[[1]]
#[1] "No duplicates"

#[[2]]
#[1] "2"

#[[3]]
#[1] "No duplicates"
```

---

Or using `duplicated`

```
lapply(list, function(x) unique(x$X2[duplicated(x$X2)|duplicated(x$X2, 
          fromLast = TRUE)]))
```

---

Or another option is to `stack` after extracting the column and get the index of duplicate elements with `table` and `which`

```
which(table(stack(setNames(lapply(list, `[[`, "X2"),
      seq_along(list)))[2:1]) > 1, arr.ind = TRUE)
```

---

Or another option is

```
library(tidyverse)
map(list, ~ .x %>%
              count(X2) %>%
              filter(n > 1) %>%
              pull(X2))
```

#### data

```
list <- list(structure(list(X1 = c("a", "d", "g", "j"), X2 = 1:4, X3 = c("b", 
"e", "h", "k"), X4 = c("c", "f", "i", "l")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L)), structure(list(X1 = c("a", "d", "g", "j"), X2 = c(1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L), X3 = c("b", "e", "h", "k"), X4 = c("c", "f", "i", 
"l")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L)), structure(list(
    X1 = c("a", "d", "g", "j"), X2 = 1:4, X3 = c("b", "e", "h", 
    "k"), X4 = c("c", "f", "i", "l")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L)))
```